# Updating (from the inverse side) bidirectional many-to-many relationships in Doctrine 2?

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

`Customer` is the inverse side of "keywords/customers" relationship with `Keyword`:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Keyword", mappedBy="customers",
 *     cascade={"persist", "remove"}
 * )
 */
protected $keywords;
```

When creating a new customer, one should select one or more keywords. The entity form field is:

```php
$form->add($this->factory->createNamed('entity', 'keywords', null, array(
    'class'    => 'Acme\HelloBundle\Entity\Keyword',
    'property' => 'select_label',
    'multiple' => true,
    'expanded' => true,
)));
```

In my controller code, after binding the request and check if form is valid, I need to persist both the customer and all customer/keyword(s) associations, that is the join table.

However customer is the inverse side, so this is not working:

```php
if($request->isPost()) {
    $form->bindRequest($request);

    if(!$form->isValid()) {
        return array('form' => $form->createView());
    }

    // Valid form here   
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $em->persist($customer);    
    $em->flush();
}
```

Event with "cascade" option, this code fails. `$customer->getKeywords()` will return `Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection`, which holds only selected keywords.

Should I manually check which keyword was removed/added and then update from the owning side?

Comment: I posted my solution [here][1]. Hope it will help.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27113108/3133441

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, found the way, even if I'm not fully satisfied. The key was [this example](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) form collection field type. Basically what's happening with my previous form definition was:

```php
$customer->getKeywords() = $postData; // $postData is somewhere in form framework
```

And that is just an assignment of a collection (of selected keywords) to customer keywords. No method were invoked on `Keyword` instances (owning side). The key option is `by_reference` (for me it's just a bad name, but anyways...):

```php
$form
    ->add($this->factory->createNamed('entity', 'keywords', null, array(
        // ...
        'by_reference' => false
    ))
);
```

This way the form framework is going to call the setter, that is `$customer->setKeywords(Collection $keywords)`. In that method, you can "tell" the owning side to store your association:

```php
public function setKeywords(Collection $keywords)
{
    foreach($keywords as $keyword) {
        $keyword->addCustomer($this); // Owning side call!
    }

    $this->keywords = $keywords;

    return $this;
}
```

(Always check for duplicate instances on the owning side, using `contains` method).

At this point, only checked keywords will be added (`$keyword` argument). There is the need to manage removal of unchecked keywords (controller side):

```php
$originalKeywords = $customer->getKeywords()->toArray(); // When GET or POST

// When POST and form valid
$checkedKeywords = $customer->getKeywords()->toArray(); // Thanks to setKeywords

// Loop over all keywords
foreach($originalKeywords as $keyword) {
    if(!in_array($keyword, $checkedKeywords)) { // Keyword has been unchecked
        $keyword->removeCustomer($customer);
        $manager->persist($keyword);
    }
}
```

Ugly, but works. I would have the code for removal moved to the `Customer` class, but it's not possible at all. If you'll find a better solution, let me know!

Answer (score 3):

I use slightly different solution than @gredmo. From [doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal): you can use Orphan Removal when you satisfy this assumption:

> When using the `orphanRemoval=true` option Doctrine makes the assumption that the entities are privately owned and will **NOT** be reused by other entities. If you neglect this assumption your entities will get deleted by Doctrine even if you assigned the orphaned entity to another one.

I have this entity class:

```
class Contract {
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ContractParticipant", mappedBy="contract", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 **/
}
protected $participants;
```

form processing (pseudo code):

```
    // $_POST carry the Contract entity values

    $received = [];

    foreach ($_POST['participants'] as $key => $participant) {

        if ((!$relation = $collection->get($key))) {
            // new entity
            $collection[$key] = $relation = $relationMeta->newInstance();

        } else {
            // editing existing entity
        }

        $received[] = $key;
        $this->mapper->save($relation, $participant);   // map POST data to entity
    }

    foreach ($collection as $key => $relation) {
        if ($this->isAllowedRemove() && !in_array($key, $received)) {
            // entity has been deleted
            unset($collection[$key]);
        }
    }
```

Don't forget to persist the entity end flush. Flush also deletes the removed entities.

```
    $this->em->persist($entity);
    $this->em->flush();
```